# " == " change results of getClass()?

Tags: java, equals

I implemented equals() method like this

```
 public boolean equals(Object y)        // does this board equal y?
{
    if (y == null) return false;
    if (this == y) return true;
    if (this.getClass() != y.getClass()) return false;
    Board that = (Board) y; 
    return Arrays.equals(this.newblocks, that.newblocks);
}
```

and I test this method using

```
    Board initial = new Board(newblocks);
    Board initial2 = new Board(newblocks);
    StdOut.println(initial.equals(initial2));
```

However, the result is false. I found after the line y == null, the class of y change from Board to string. Why does this happen?

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

Edit:

Here is a MVCE.

```
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.In;
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdOut;
import java.util.Arrays;

public final class Board {
private int[][] newblocks;

public Board(int[][] blocks)           // construct a board from an n-by-n array of newblocks
{ 
    newblocks = new int[blocks.length][blocks.length];
    //              this.blocks = new int[blocks.length][blocks.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++) 
        for (int j = 0; j < blocks.length; j++) 
        newblocks[i][j] = blocks[i][j];
}
public int dimension()                 // board dimension n
{ return newblocks.length; }

public boolean equals(Object y)        // does this board equal y?
{
    if (y == null) return false;
    if (this == y) return true;
    if (this.getClass() != y.getClass()) return false;
    Board that = (Board) y; 
    return Arrays.equals(this.newblocks, that.newblocks);
}

public String toString()               // string representation of this board (in the output format specified below)
{ 
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
    s.append(dimension());
    s.append("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < dimension(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < dimension(); j++) {
            s.append(newblocks[i][j]);
            s.append("\t");
        }
        s.append("\n");
    }
    return s.toString();
} 

public static void main(String[] args) // unit tests (not graded)
{
    In in = new In(args[0]);
    int n = in.readInt();
    int[][] newblocks = new int[n][n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        newblocks[i][j] = in.readInt();
    Board initial = new Board(newblocks);
    Board initial2 = new Board(newblocks);
    StdOut.println(initial);
    StdOut.println(initial.equals(initial2));

}
```

}

The test document is a txt file like

3

1   2   3
0   4   8
7   6   5
The first "3" shows it is a 3x3 matrix, and the next nine numbers belong to the matrix.

Comment: The class of y does not change to String unless you pass in a String. You generally don't want to be comparing classes in an equals method implementation anyway, google 'how to implement equals in Java' or take a look at the implementation in _Effective Java_ if you have a copy handy. Also take a look at [MCVE]

Comment: Can you show us the constructor of `Board`?  The issue might be there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I found after the line y == null, the class of y change from Board to string.

I can state categorically that you are wrong about that.  What you are describing / proposing is **impossible** in Java.  An object's fundamental type (as returned by `this.getClass()`) will not change.  Not ever<sup>1</sup>.

What *must* be going on is that `y` is not an instance of `Board` in the first place.

Alternatively, there is a mismatch between the code that you have shown us and reality<sup>2</sup>.

If you want us to understand / explain what is *actually* going on, you will need to write an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and share it with us.  (And I suspect that the process of doing that will reveal ... to you ... what the real problem is.)

---

<sup>1 - Since `y` is a local variable, not even a memory visibility anomaly could do this.  The only way that this could happen is if you wrote some native code that trampled on object headers from a different thread.  If you do that kind of stuff, your JVM is liable to crash horribly.</sup>

<sup>2 - For example, you could be calling a different overload of `equals`, OR you could have transcribed or simplified the code incorrectly, OR you could be running a different version of the code.</sup>

---

**UPDATE**

When I debug your program, it is clear that the code is not returning `false` at this line:

```
if (this.getClass() != y.getClass()) return false;
```

It is actually the call to `Arrays.equals` that is returning false.

And the reason is that `Arrays.equals(Object[], Object[])` does not compare a pair of `int[][]` objects in the way that you think.  (Read the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals-java.lang.Object:A-java.lang.Object:A-) carefully, thinking about what the elements of the `Object[]` instances actually are ... and what their `equals` methods will do.)

Hint:  Arrays.equals won't work for what you are trying to do.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. I updated a MVCE and that might help explain the problem. The class of y is definitely Board prior to y==null and string after that. I still cannot figure out the problem...

Comment: Hi thanks, it is the problem of equals. I changed them to deepEquals and that solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `==` operator never changes anything, let alone a class.

Your bug hides elsewhere (most likely in code you have not posted).

Answer (score 0):

`Arrays.equals()` compares each element using `equals()`. Since, in your case, those elements are themselves arrays, the equality check is failing. The solution is to use [`Arrays.deepEquals()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepEquals(java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object[])), which will compare array elements at any depth.

Comment: Hi thanks for commenting. There are two points that I'm not so clear.

Comment: lol I went to debug after typing that and forgot to complete. The question is solved, and it is the problem of deepEquals. Thanks.

Comment: @polkolp No problem. Please [accept this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/304954) if it solved your problem.